# Get host key of an ssh server in base 64

Tags: python, macos, ssh, terminal, paramiko

I'm using paramiko and I need the host key of an ssh server in base 64 for the following line:

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.decodestring('...'))
```

Does anyone know of a way either through the Mac OS X terminal, in a python script, or something else to find this? Thanks

Comment: I'm curious to know *why* you need the host key of an ssh server. In the snippet above, what do you plan to do with `key`?

Comment: Specifying the key is a way of verifying from the client that the server is who they say they are. (i.e. not a man-in-the-middle attack.)

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the server's public key from the server itself, without having to authenticate yourself to the server.

```
import paramiko
import socket
import sys

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.connect((arg, 22))
        trans = paramiko.transport.Transport(sock)
        trans.start_client()
        k = trans.get_remote_server_key()
        # On my machine, this returns a paramiko.RSAKey
        print k.get_base64()
```

Comment: I think you were probably going to use arg to decide which server to connect to rather than statically to localhost.

Comment: When I put it into my code, it seems to entirely skip at least the print statement and possibly more. It then proceeds to call on error on                             `key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.decodestring(k.get_base64()))`

Comment: @PhoenixRising 1) I suspect that you included the `for` statement in your program. That for statement iterates over the command-line arguments to this very short program. You probably don't want that. Delete the `for` line and adjust the indent accordingly. 2) The assignment line you mention is more simply written: `key = k`.

Comment: If I delete the `for` line, what do you suggest I do with this line:                  `sock.connect((arg, 22))`

Comment: @PhoenixRising - replace `arg` with either the name or IP address of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do this only once, or do you need to be able to programmatically grab the host key at runtime? If only once,

```
ssh -v <hostname>
```

will show you the host key.

Comment: This will show the fingerprint but not the key -- it's based on the key but is not the key.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from paramiko.client import SSHClient

>>> client = SSHClient()
>>> client.connect('hostname')
# This probably will fail since there's no auth set here
>>> rsa_key = client.get_transport().get_remote_server_key()
<paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey object at 0x109305e90>
# however, this still exists
>>> rsa_key.get_base64()
u'AAAAB3NzaC1y...Nhd'
```

Since you're using paramiko already, you probably will want to just stop at rsa_key and not make a new one with get_base64() since rsa_key is of RSAKey type already.

A server can define a non-RSA key as well (or multiple) but if you know that it only returns RSA, this will obviously always return RSA.  It will depend on which key is negotiated.

Comment: Could you help me figure out why I get this error                        `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_remote_server_key'`

Comment: This means that client.get_transport() isn't responding with a Transport object.  Very likely, this would mean client.connect failed -- it would have raised an exception in this case.